# Google Compute Engine start up python script doesn't run at boot

Tags: python, bash, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to set up a short list of start-up commands for my Google Compute engine instance, but no matter what I do it doesn't execute.

The script is supposed to start a daemon screen session and run a python script inside the screen session.

This works fine from the command prompt but does not execute at all as a start-up script:

```
#! /bin/bash
screen -dmS mhsession && screen -S mhsession -X stuff 'cd stream
python3 streamer.py 'ABCD'
'
```

UPDATE, output from /var/log/syslog:

```
May 16 08:25:27 netherlands startup-script: INFO startup-script: No screen session found.
May 16 08:25:27 netherlands startup-script: INFO startup-script: No screen session found.
May 16 08:25:27 netherlands startup-script: INFO startup-script: Return code 1.
May 16 08:25:27 netherlands startup-script: INFO Finished running startup scripts.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is the `stream` folder? Your start up script is run from `/`, not `/username` or `/root`.

`ssh` into the Compute Engine and have a look at `/var/log/syslog`, search for `start` or `startup` to see what's blocking your script from running.

`cat /var/log/syslog | grep start`

Comment: That is super helpful thank you! The stream folder is under my username, so that's the first thing that was off.

Second, it seems that it is a different issue keeping this from running at start-up:


`May 16 08:25:27 netherlands startup-script: INFO startup-script: No screen session found.
May 16 08:25:27 netherlands startup-script: INFO startup-script: No screen session found.
May 16 08:25:27 netherlands startup-script: INFO startup-script: Return code 1.
May 16 08:25:27 netherlands startup-script: INFO Finished running startup scripts.`

Comment: so with that info, I went and changed it to screen -S test -d -m python3 stream.py

and that works!