# Startup Script in Metadata Not Running (Python, Google Compute Engine, Cloud Storage Trigger)

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine, metadata

I have an app running on Google App Engine, and an AI running on Google Compute Engine. I'm triggering the VM instance to start on a change in a Google Cloud Storage bucket, and have a start-up script that I attempt to store in the metadata of the GCE instance. My cloud functions looks like this:

```
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


def start(event, context):
    file = event
    print(file["id"])

    string = file["id"]

    new_string = string.split('/')
    user_id = new_string[1]
    payment_id = new_string[2]
    name = new_string[3]

    print(name)

    if name == "uploadcomplete.txt":
        startup_script = """ #! /bin/bash
                sudo su username
                cd directory/directory
                python analysis.py -- gs://location/{userId}/{paymentId}
                """.format(userId=user_id, paymentId=payment_id)
        # initialize compute api
        service = build('compute', 'v1', cache_discovery=False)
        print('VM Instance starting')
        project = 'zephyrd'
        zone = 'us-east1-c'
        instance = 'zephyr-a'

        # get metadata fingerprint in order to set new metadata
        metadata = service.instances().get(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance)
        metares = metadata.execute()
        fingerprint = metares["metadata"]["fingerprint"]

        # set new metadata
        bodydata = {"fingerprint": fingerprint,
                    "items": [{"key": "startup-script", "value": startup_script}]}
        meta = service.instances().setMetadata(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance,
                                               body=bodydata).execute()
        print(meta)

        # confirm new metdata
        instanceget = service.instances().get(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance).execute()
        print("'New Metadata:", instanceget['metadata'])
        print(instanceget)

        # start VM
        request = service.instances().start(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance)
        response = request.execute()
        print('VM Instance started')
        print(response)
```

The VM starts, but the startup script does not run. The script has been simplified for the purposes of the question, but this is just a basic command I'm trying to run. I would add the script directly to the metadata in the console, but I use values from the cloud function trigger to run commands in the VM. What am I missing?

I've attempted to set the metadata in two ways:

```
"items": [{"key": "startup-script", "value": startup_script}]
```

as well as:

```
"items": [{"startup-script" : startup_script}]
```

Neither work. The commands run beautifully if I manually type them in the shell.

Comment: The solution in this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307185/google-compute-engine-start-up-python-script-doesnt-run-at-boot) seems like the solution. It is similar to what Juancki suggested below.

Answer (score 2):

Look into your logs to determine why its not executing.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#viewing_startup_script_logs

Probably you the issue is that you are trying to execute a python script instead of a bash script.

Your startup script should be something like:

```
#! /bin/bash

# ...
python3 paht/to/python_script.py
```

Comment: So the script is running, but it doesn't run the script commands in the home directory. It's like it creates a special startup environment first, runs the commands (with errors), and then opens into the full enivronment. @Juancki

Comment: @KhariKisile It seems to run scripts on root. If you do `sudo su root` you should see the changes there